# How can I add the lines from file to Arraylist of Line objects?

Tags: java

I want to add lines from the text file into the ArrayList of Line objects so when I want to add lines to ArrayList. I am getting an error in the function of readLines()

```
private static ArrayList<Line> readLines(File filename, ArrayList<Line> x)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(filename);
        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            String lines = fileScan.nextLine();
            x.add(new Line(lines));
        }
        return x;
    }
    class Line {
        private String line;
        private int numLetter;
        private int numDigit;

        public Line(String line) {
            this.line = line;
            numLetter = 0;
            numDigit = 0;
            setStats();
        }
        public void setLine(String line) {
            this.line = line;
            setStats();
        }
        public void setStats() {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) {
                    numLetter++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(i))) {
                    numDigit++;
                }
            }
        }
        public String getLine() {
            return line;
        }
        public int getNumLetter() {
            return numLetter;
        }
        public int getNumDigit() {
            return numDigit;
        }
     }
```

so, the IntelliJ say me that cannot possible to use `x.add(new Line(lines))` How can I fix this problem.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: x.add(new Line(lines)), It gives me error

Comment: What is the description of the error that IntelliJ displays for that line?

Comment: It says java:non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static contex